# SQL views in Yesod/persistent

Tags: haskell, persistent, yesod, sql-view

In http://www.yesodweb.com/book/persistent there is no mention of SQL views.

I (even in imperative languages) have been very fond of immutable database schema design.  i.e. only INSERTs and SELECTs - UPDATEs and DELETEs are not used.

This has the advantage of preserving all history, at the expense of making the current 'state' a relatively expensive pure function of the history in the DB.

e.g. there is not a 'user' table, just 'user_created', 'user_password_updated' and 'user_deleted' tables, which are unified in a 'user' SQL VIEW, showing the current state of users.

How should I work with VIEWs in Persistent?  Should I use Persistent at all - is it (ironically for Haskell) too tightly focused on a mutable DB for my use-case?

Comment: Could you please clarify? From your question is not clear if you want to use a SQL View in Yesod or if you want to manage (in the sense of maintining view integrity constraints) a SQL View from Yesod. Thanks!

Comment: Ideally, I would like to manage SQL Views from Yesod.  If that is not possible, I could create them directly in the DB, though I would still want the create a Haskell type for the records in the view.  I think the major difficulty will be with the type system, as the rows in the 'user' SQL VIEW will not be the same "shape" as the rows in the 'user_created' table, even though they will share the same id.

Comment: Well, is you manage the view as a DB view you can use it as a normal SQL table (with a single 'shape'), that is, you have a single record type for the view. On the other hand, you have to manage the single table by yourself, but I think the problem is mitigated by you not using updates/deletes. My two cents here: use an SQL view to have a read-only table, and simply put inserts into your main tables (user, user_created, user_passord_updated): read logic in SQL view, safe management of inserts (or updates, if you want) in Haskell. I hope I got your requirements right, if not just let me know!

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I'll have a try this weekend and see how it goes.

Comment: @chrisdew I know this question is old but.. how **did** it go? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's been a long time since the question was asked, but I thought it was worth 
responding because seven years later the answer has not changed and I really like
your idea about keeping the old versions of tables around and reading them with
views! One drawback of this approach is that using Template Haskell in `persistent`
will slow down compile times a lot. Once I had a database of about 50 tables in 
`persistent` Template Haskell and it took over half an hour to compile if it was
ever changed.

Yesod's [persistent](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent) does not support 
SQL views and I doubt it ever will because it intends to be database agnostic.
Currently it looks like it supports CouchDB, MongoDB, MySQL , PostgreSQL, Redis
and SQLite. Not all of these databases support SQL style views so it would be
hard to abstract over all of them.

Where `persistent` excels at is at providing an easy way to create a set of 
Haskell types that serialize to and
from different databases. It provides with type class instances and functions to
do single table queries and these work really well. If you want to do join queries on an SQL database that
you are interfacing with `persistent`, then you can use [esqueleto](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/esqueleto),
a type safe EDSL for SQL join queries.

As far as handling SQL Views in Haskell, I have not come across any tool yet.
You can either use `rawQuery` which will work but be harder to maintain or
you can build your own tool around one the Haskell DB interfaces like [postgresql-simple](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/postgresql-simple),
which is what `persistent` does. In fact, you can even start with the `persistent` 
source code of whatever database you are using and build an SQL View EDSL as you 
need. In a closed-source project I helped build a custom PostgreSQL 
interface based on some of `persistent`'s ideas and types, but without using
an Template Haskell because the compile time was too slow.